# Play YouTube Video with URL on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a YouTube video from a URL in my iOS app using MPMoviePlayerController but I just get a black screen and nothing plays. What am I doing wrong? I have verified that the url is correct and is being passed the correct videoId.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", videoIDString];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Comment: That URL is a youtube webpage. To play the video in a native player, you probably need a youtube-specific library.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the YouTube iOS Player Helper, which lets you do something like [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"] https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper